# How to remove border from text area?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is divided into four divs. First one is the header , second one contains the date field, third one has the text area and last div has a button.
[image]

The structure is like this
Main Div(crtpost-form)
->Create P(crtpost-form-1)
->Date(crtpost-form-4)
->Text Area(crtpost-form-2)
->Button(crtpost-form-3)

In the text area(crtpost-text) I've changed the color of the top and bottom border to #d1d5db which is working correctly but I don't want border left and right(I had set it to none but it was showing a black border with the same thickness as that of border top and bottom so I commented it and after that I'am getting the border as shown in the image). How can I remove that?

```css
.crtpost-form {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
  /* background-color: #f6f6f6; */
  /* background-color: #242526; */
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* border: #27777a;
        border-style: solid; */
}

.crtpost-form-1 {
  height: 10%;
  background: #27777a;
  color: white;
  /* background: #112f8e; */
  /* color: #e4e6eb; */
  /* color: #d1d5db; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.crtpost-form-2 {
  height: 60%;
  /* background-color: bisque; */
  background: white;
}

.crtpost-text {
  border-top: #d1d5db;
  border-bottom: #d1d5db;
  /* border-left: none;
        border-right: none; */
  /* border: none; */
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* width: 150%;
        height: 150%; */
  resize: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  /* line-height: 2rem; */
}

.crtpost-form-3 {
  height: 15%;
  /* background-color: cadetblue; */
  background: white;
  text-align: end;
  /* margin-right: 20px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.crtpost-form-4 {
  height: 15%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<form class="crtpost-form">
  <div class="crtpost-form">
    <label>Date</label>
    <div class="crtpost-form-1">
      <h2>Create Post</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="crtpost-form-4">
      <input class="crtpost-input" type="date">
    </div>
    <div class="crtpost-form-2">
      <textarea class="crtpost-text" placeholder="How was your day?"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="crtpost-form-3">
      <button class="crtpost-btn" type="submit">Publish</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant html please?

Comment: sure..i'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `border-style` and add borders like `border-top:1px solid #d1d5db;`
then set border-left and border-right none

```css
textarea{
    border-top: 1px solid #d1d5db;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d1d5db;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```